# After open google chrome Ubuntu 11.10 crashes all browsers 

Tags: 11.10

I have been using ubuntu 11.10 for 1 year,today it made me surprised.
When I open google chrome it just closes itself. Firstly i thought that it is just for chrome and tried Firefox : It also closes itself and one thing more : I tried desktop programs such as image viewer it also closes itself.I restarted it but there is no changing.What can do this ? is it virus or another system problem ? I did not have any problem like this until today..

> $ google-chrome
>
> (exe:7166): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in
>   module_path: "pixmap",
>
> (exe:7201): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in
>   module_path: "pixmap", Failed to open VDPAU backend
>   libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory Segmentation fault

`libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` Solved by nvidia-current packet reinstallation.

Segfault still there.

Comment: in addition to this,mozilla can live more than chrome in this situtation.After i open Chrome closes itself in 1-2 minutes,now i can write this problem via firefox

Comment: Virus don't act like that in the Linux world. Furthermore, to be infected on linux... You've to want this ! Can you give us what happens inside the application ? Launch a terminal type "firefox" and wait it to crash, put the error here (edit your first post)

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion it's a broken plug-in.  Check in `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins` and update the question with a list

Comment: lol you may be the unique person in the world who using ubuntu 11.10 for 1 year :D , it just released at the end of thelast year

Comment: what must i write for chrome ? lol bro i meant i use ubuntu for 1 year,sorry.

Comment: i remembered that last day i used mono to run c# code,is it about mono ?

Comment: @murat You're not the only one. I'm having the same problems since two days, actually since the last update which was a kernel update + google Chrome update. Waiting for more clues.

Comment: I am facing this problem since yesterday too. There is something wrong when all browsers are crashing.

Comment: All of these clues show us there is a real problem with ubuntu updates.When i look at last days i remember i apply updates and used mono and i am wonder about which one can hurt ubuntu.If anyone can learn the solution please inform us.I searched on the ınternet a lot ant could not find any solution

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a nvidia official driver problem (libvdpau).

There is 3 options :

- First, you re-install the package from the repository. `apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-current`
- Second, you go to the [nvidia website](http://nvidia.com) and according to your hardware you download the proper driver and install it.
- ***Don't do this one :***  Last one is to reinstall the libvdpau1 : `apt-get install libvdpau1`

Finally, it don't seems to be the fault of the nvidia driver.

Comment: i installed the package,are you sure it is about libvdpau ?

Comment: The fact is the software look for "libvdpau_nvidia.so" but it doesn't exist. So yes, i'm pretty sure ;).
Re-installing the package might be the solution you're looking for.
What package did you tried ? if it's libvdpau1, I can't be sure about the results (it'll probably don't work because it's the original libvdpau, not the nvidia retouched one which is causing the segfault to your softwares)

Comment: That's okey,What about segmentation fault ?

Comment: i meant it doesn't work.What is segmentation fault?Does it hurt OS ?

Comment: Segfault happens when a program encounter an error that can't be handled properly so it close. It doesn't hurt operating system, don't worry about that : it's just a signal sent by the application.
What solution did you tried ? Cause if the first one doesn't work, the second might works.

Comment: i started with 3 now trying 1

Comment: i wrote new error above

Comment: i tried the first one but error still occurs

Comment: Open a terminal, type : `sudo updatedb` and `sudo locate libvdpau`, paste the output here. (Look to my previous comment)

Comment: /usr/lib/libvdpau.so.1
/usr/lib/libvdpau.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.1
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.280.13
/usr/lib/vdpau/libvdpau_trace.so.1
/usr/lib/vdpau/libvdpau_trace.so.1.0.0
/usr/share/doc/libvdpau1
/usr/share/doc/libvdpau1/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libvdpau1/copyright
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libvdpau1.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libvdpau1.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libvdpau1.postinst

Comment: /var/lib/dpkg/info/libvdpau1.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libvdpau1.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libvdpau1.symbols

Comment: i did everything you said but it seems error still occurs

Comment: yes i reboot it

Comment: i also tried with firefox,it crashed but i can not reach the error list.Hovewer it does not crash like chrome so i can write the solution here.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't crash like chrome" ?
And why can't you get the output ? There's just nothing written ?
Btw, is other application (not browser) still crash ?

Comment: @murat - this is a Q&A site - the way we work is by re-editing your question with new information.  Please do NOT hold a conversation in comments.  Please tidy up by deleting your comments & copying relevant information into your question.

Comment: @Bahaïka - a similar comment for you - just keep re-editing your answer with new information and remove old irrelevant information.  Please tidy up your comments by removing them and copying important information into your answer.  Thank-you.

Comment: Well, the suggestions presented here did not help